# Problems using Core Data generated accessors

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

So I've got two entities, one called "List" and one called "Task". Each of them has multiple attributes and one relationship. The relationship for List is called "hasTasks" and it is a one to many relationship.

This is the Task.h file that is generated for me.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Task;

@interface List : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * number;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * tasks;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * totalTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *hasTasks;
@end

@interface List (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addHasTasksObject:(Task *)value;
- (void)removeHasTasksObject:(Task *)value;
- (void)addHasTasks:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeHasTasks:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Now whenever I call something along the lines of

```
[self.list addHasTasksObject:task];
```

my app crashes when it gets to this point. Anybody have an idea why this is? If you need to see any more of my code, don't hesitate to ask. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the error message on crash?

Comment: There is no error message

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem and I fixed it in the .xcdatamodeld file.  I had accidentally selected the ordered arrangement checkbox for a relationship without re-generating the NSManagedObject classes. Unchecking this box and re-building solved this problem for me.  If you are still having a problem, try re-generating your NSManagedObject classes.

Answer (score 1):

will u please post your core data add objects method.Let me see that method.Try this..

```
- (void)addButtonClicked:(id)sender

{

    if (![nameField.text isEqualToString:@""])

    {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    ///Entity declaration....

        CountryNames *country = (CountryNames *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CountryNames"
                                        inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
        ///take a array for relation ship atribute...
        for (int i = 0; i < citiesArray.count; i++)
        {   ///atribute declaration...
            CityNames *citiesNames = (CityNames *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CityNames"
                                        inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];

            [country addRelationtocitiesObject:citiesNames];

            citiesNames.cityName = [citiesArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"%@",citiesNames.cityName);

            NSError *error;

            if (![appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {}

        }

        country.name = nameField.text;

        NSError *error;

        if (![appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {}
        //  ListOfCountryDetails *viewList=[[ListOfCountryDetails alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: As in the one from [self.list addHasTasksObject:task];? The implementation for that is dynamically generated and it does not show it in my code.

Comment: means it saved in database and not showing in your application ?